# Excel VBA timer macro

Tags: excel, vba, time, timer

Can you help me , please? I need do some stopwatch where if stopwatch obtained for example 10s so system add number 1 to some cell.

I have stopwatch but I don't know to do add some number to cell at some time value which I set

Answer (score 1):

```
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))
```

then put your code to change .value of desired range to 1. Not 100% precise, though.